# It gives me an syntax error at "return Price". I don't know what I am doing wrong

Tags: python

Each line in the file contains the average price for a gallon of gas on a specific date. Each line is formatted in the following way:

```
MM-DD-YYYY:Price
```

MM is the two-digit month, DD is the two-digit day, and YYYY is the four-digit year. Price is the average price per gallon of gas on the specified date.

You are to write one or more programs that read the contents of the file and perform the following calculations:

Average Price Per Year: Calculate the average price of gas per year, for each year in the file. (The file’s data starts in April of 1993, and it ends in August 2013. Use the data that is present for the years 1993 and 2013.)

Sample run:

```
The average price in 1993 was $1.07
The average price in 1994 was $1.08
The average price in 1995 was $1.16
The average price in 1996 was $1.24
The average price in 1997 was $1.24
The average price in 1998 was $1.07
The average price in 1999 was $1.18
The average price in 2000 was $1.52
The average price in 2001 was $1.46
The average price in 2002 was $1.39
The average price in 2003 was $1.60
The average price in 2004 was $1.89
The average price in 2005 was $2.31
The average price in 2006 was $2.62
The average price in 2007 was $2.84
The average price in 2008 was $3.30
The average price in 2009 was $2.41
The average price in 2010 was $2.84
The average price in 2011 was $3.58
The average price in 2012 was $3.68
The average price in 2013 was $3.65
```

As of now I have this:

```
#Opening GasPrice.txt 
infile = open('C:/Users/Eeshaan M/Downloads/GasPrices.txt/')
 
#Read file content using deadline 
gasPrices = float(infile.readline())
 
count = 0
# Strips the newline character 
for line in gasPrices:
    count += 1
    print("Line{}: {}".format(count, line.strip())) 
return Price
 
#Find average of price per year 
averagePricePerYear = sum(gasPrice)/len(gasPrice)
#Find average of price per month 
averagePricePerMonth = sum(gasPrice)/12
#Find Highest 
print('Highest is ', max(gasPrices))
#Find Lowest 
print('Lowest is ', min(gasPrices))
#Find Lowest to Highest 
sorted_gasPrice = sorted(gasPrices) 
print(sorted_gasPrice)
#Find Highest to Lowest 
desendingOrder=gasPrice.sort(reverse = True) 
print(desendingOrder)
```

It gives me an syntax error at "return Price"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi Eeshaan, I updated your code formatting (hopefully I didn't change the indention of your original lines). Is there a place where you define the variable called `Price`? If not, I wonder if that is part of your issue?

Comment: Frankly there are a lot of errors in the code. Other than doing your homework for you, you should just start over and get one thing working at a time.

Comment: wow @summea you should have noticed he uses return outside a function ...

Comment: can you share the data in `GasPrices.txt`. There are way too many errors in this code to fix. It is best you rewrite the program. You need to read each row, determine which year it falls under, then calculate average for that year. How are you keeping track of the values in each year? dictionary? dataframe?

Comment: The error message actually says *SyntaxError: 'return' outside function*. Even if that was not clear enough for you to understand, you should have reported the *whole* error message. If you ask a question but you present an edited or retyped or redacted version of the error you get, you may leave out information that helps in solve your problem. We are here to help you. Help us to help you by describing the problem in full.

Answer (score 1):

`return` cannot be used like you did, `return` statements can only appear inside functions. In this case, just remove that line.